# Style a table row with background color and border radius

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a table row with 2 columns , and I would like to put a background color with a border-radius.

```html
<table>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td class="d-inline-block ltr font-14 font-weight-bold"> Price:</td>
      <td class="text-right text-primary"> 1600$ </td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

[image]

Without encountering this problem by giving the background color only to tds, which leaves the middle part uncolored.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
tr td:first-child { 
  border-top-left-radius: 150px; 
  border-bottom-left-radius: 150px; 
}
  
tr td:last-child { 
  border-top-right-radius: 150px; 
  border-bottom-right-radius: 150px; 
}

td {
  padding: 12px;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: solid 0px #000;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td class="d-inline-block ltr font-14 font-weight-bold"> Price:    </td>
      <td class="text-right text-primary"> 1600$ </td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: This approach works, but the thing is this will leave empty space between the two tds

Comment: @agoumi That's why i added `border-collapse: collapse;`, What CSS framework are you using?

Comment: i am using TailwindCss.

Comment: @agoumi Do you have any other styles other than tailwind ? Cause I tested it with Tailwind It's working.